Django allauth: Unable to get Access token when login using google social account
I am using django allauth for google authentication.
settings.py
from pathlib import Path
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-9#c!e&s(-o9-6u^mt#w(w6s$ober^f(m45)=f)=m&zo1$dlcg&'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'allauth', # Social login App
    'allauth.account', # login App
    'allauth.socialaccount', # Social login App
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google', # Google login App
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "API", # API APP
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    "allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware"
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'MassMail.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.normpath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request', # requirements for django-all-auth
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'MassMail.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Google Authentication
SITE_ID = 1

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

# SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'  # Redirect after successful login
# SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/login/error/'  # Redirect on login error
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/profile/'
# ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
# SOCIALACCOUNT_ONLY = True

# Provider specific settings
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'FETCH_USERINFO' : True,
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        },
        'OAUTH_PKCE_ENABLED': True,
    }
}



# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

project urls.py file
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("accounts/", include("API.urls")),
]


API urls.py:
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path("profile/",views.ProfileView.as_view(),name='user_profile'),
    path('', include("allauth.urls")),
]


I am getting logged in successfully but I am unable to get access token.
I am using login with google and when i see the database there is not access token stored in it.
How can i get the access token from the google login?
Your answer would be a great help for me.

did you find a solution?

Allauth module had a lot of issues so I switched to social-auth-app-django
